# Outlook 2019 applies rules inconsistently when email comes in, but works perfectly with "run now"

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2007, rules, microsoft-outlook-2019

I just upgraded from Outlook 2007 to Outlook 2019, and that upgrade included a bunch of client side rules ( we don't use exchange server, just normal POP and IMAP ).  For some reason, when the emails come in, the rules are inconsistently applied.  So it might get moved to a folder, but a category might not get applied, or it might not get auto-marked as read.  If I then go into "Run Rules Now" and run all the rules in my unread mail, it applies all of them perfectly, with no errors.  I tried scanpst on the PST file in question, I tried removing the the SRS files so they would be regenerated.  So far nothing has  fixed it.

Number of emails received at once varies.  Sometimes it is a lot, sometimes it is just a trickle.  In both cases, rules don't fully apply sometimes.  In other words, it applies an action to move to a folder, but does not assign a category.

I do have quite a few rules, and they tend to have just one or two conditions.

Regardless, all rules work fine if I "run now", no problems at all.  It is only when they come in that they are not applied completely in all cases.  As an example, I have 1 rule, see below:
[image]
So what happens at first, before "run rule now", is that the email gets moved to "spence interface" folder just fine, but does not have category applied.  I simply "run rules now", select all the rules, and click "Run Now", and it works.  So the problem is not the rule, per se, but the application of the rule when the email first comes in.

My normal way of getting around the issue is this:

1. Go to unread email folder
2. Click rules
3. Click "Run Rules Now"
4. Click "Select all"
5. Click "Run Now"
6. Check to make sure any uncompleted rules are now completed

This always works, so the problem is not the rules themselves, as far as I can see.  Any ideas?

More information:
Here is a perfect example of my problem.  Note that I did NOT apply the rules with "Run Now" yet, this is exactly as it appeared after downloading the emails.  Note that both emails obey the "NORM files at" rule, but only one applies one of the 4 PBM category rules.  That inconsistency is what is confusing me.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the PBM category rules are below the NORM rule, they won't be triggered if they already triggered the NORM rule, because it has stop processing more rules.

Comment: Thanks.  In my case, PBM Category rule is above NORM rule (it is near the top, NORM rule is farther down).  My problem is that sometimes, when the email comes in, the rule/rules are NOT triggered, sometimes they are.  Obviously, it always works with "Run Now", and that is to be expected.  But when the email first comes in, it is inconsistent.  Let's say we have multiple emails that meet the same criteria.  For some emails, rules work perfectly (all rules get applied), for others things do not work perfectly.  Seems to more consistently work when I open Outlook, but even that is not consistent.